# How can I show texts like score or time in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I have used the stage method. But it doesn't work. I am new in game developing. Help me out please.

Comment: Use a label. Add it to your stage. Read on up scene2d.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Label`, If you're using [scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) in this way :

```
public class GdxText extends ApplicationAdapter {

    Stage stage;
    Label scoreLabel;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        stage=new Stage();

        Label.LabelStyle labelStyle=new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.RED);
        scoreLabel=new Label(String.format("%03d",0),labelStyle);

        Table table =new Table();
        table.defaults().pad(2);

        table.add(new Label("SCORE :",labelStyle));
        table.add(scoreLabel);
        table.setPosition(200,300);

        stage.addActor(table);
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }

    public void increase(){
        CharSequence value=scoreLabel.getText();
        int v= Integer.valueOf(value.toString());
        scoreLabel.setText(String.format("%03d", ++v));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.getViewport().update(width,height,true);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }
}
```

I am using default font for this test, you can use own font. Whenever you want to increase value of score call `increase()` method, that increase your score by one.

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this technique before. But now I get why that wasn't working. I put this two lines of code   (stage.draw();
        stage.act();)      between sb.begin() and sb.end().    But putting these lines after sb.end() did work.

Comment: you need to use one batch at a time, when you call `stage.draw()`, a batch `begin()` called internally and after drawing `end()` called so keep your batch separate.